# What are the best sites to learn about formal languages, automata, algorithms and data structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, automata, formal-languages

I'd like to know what are the best sites to learn about formal languages, automata, algorithms and data structures. Preferable with many solved questions... 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I prefer is., a best book " On Theory of Automation", [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Automata-Languages-Computation-Edition/dp/0321455363](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321455363) .,

I have read this book., superb it is.

Answer (score 0):

visit http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code

You can compare also structure of programs on examples.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned what kind of algorithms you want to learn. Anyway for basic algorithms and data structures TopCoder algorithm tutorial's page is a good place to start. Visit http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index&module=Static